# What does a[k++] = l[i++] notation mean

Tags: java, mergesort

I'm trying to figure out this merge function for merge sort, but I don't understand the line a[k++] = l[i++]. Can someone give me the non-reduced version of what that would look like?

```
public static void merge(int[] a, int[] l, int[] r, int left, int right) {
 
    int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0;
    while (i < left && j < right) {
        if (l[i] <= r[j]) {
            a[k++] = l[i++];
        }
        else {
            a[k++] = r[j++];
        }
    }
    while (i < left) {
        a[k++] = l[i++];
    }
    while (j < right) {
        a[k++] = r[j++];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
a[k++] = l[i++];
```

is the same as

```
a[k] = l[i];
k = k + 1;
i = i + 1;
```

---

Suppose `k = 3` and `i = 5`.

```
a[k++] = l[i++];
print(k);
print(i);
```

> **OUTPUT: 4 6**

is the same as

```
a[k] = l[i];
k = k + 1;
i = i + 1;
print(k);
print(i);
```

> **OUTPUT: 4 6**

Comment: @chqrlie, in Java? Or are you talking about C?

Comment: @Taschi: indeed I was referring to C or C++. I added the missing language tag. Evaluation order is specified in the [java language specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.7), so even such horrors as `a[i++] = b[i++]` are defined. Yet the note says: *It is recommended that code not rely crucially on this specification. Code is usually clearer when each expression contains at most one side effect, as its outermost operation, and when code does not depend on exactly which exception arises as a consequence of the left-to-right evaluation of expressions.*